# Aggregating timeranges MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, aggregation, window-functions

Give the following table which shows the login times on a computer, i would greatly appreciate if someone could help me write a MS SQL query which will provide the aggregated timespans in table 2:

Table1 (the data):

```
Usrkey  Username    DateTime_From           DateTime_To

1       Fox         2012-01-01 08:00    2012-01-01 08:15
1       Fox         2012-01-01 08:20    2012-01-01 08:25
2       Foxi        2012-01-01 09:30    2012-01-01 09:40
2       Foxi        2012-01-01 10:20    2012-01-01 10:25
1       Fox         2012-01-01 10:30    2012-01-01 10:35
1       Fox         2012-01-01 11:00    2012-01-01 11:40
2       Foxi        2012-01-01 12:50    2012-01-01 13:25
2       Foxi        2012-01-02 08:20    2012-01-02 08:25
2       Foxi        2012-01-02 09:20    2012-01-02 09:25
1       Fox         2012-01-02 11:30    2012-01-02 11:45
1       Fox         2012-01-02 12:50    2012-01-02 13:00
1       Fox         2012-01-02 13:20    2012-01-02 14:00
```

Table2 (desired result):

```
Usrkey  Username    RangeFrom           RangeTo
1       Fox         2012-01-01 08:00    2012-01-01 08:25
2       Foxi        2012-01-01 09:30    2012-01-01 10:25
1       Fox         2012-01-02 10:30    2012-01-01 11:40
2       Foxi        2012-01-01 12:50    2012-01-02 09:25
1       Fox         2012-01-02 11:30    2012-01-02 14:00
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: Looks like a gaps an island question to me. There's 1,000's of answers out there on how to solve them.

Comment: I've tried with window functions and LAG and LEAD functions, but didn't get to the desired result.

Comment: So post the SQL you tried, please.

Answer (score 1):

The OP hasn't responded with what they've tried, but I still suggest they do. This is a different method, using `ROW_NUMBER()`, however, if you post what you tried using `LEAD`/`LAG`, then we can also show you were you went wrong there as well.

Anyway:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT Usrkey,
           Username,
           CONVERT(datetime2(0),DateTime_From) AS DateTime_From,
           CONVERT(datetime2(0),DateTime_To) AS DateTime_To
    FROM (VALUES (1,'Fox ','2012-01-01T08:00:00','2012-01-01T08:15:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-01T08:20:00','2012-01-01T08:25:00'),
                 (2,'Foxi','2012-01-01T09:30:00','2012-01-01T09:40:00'),
                 (2,'Foxi','2012-01-01T10:20:00','2012-01-01T10:25:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-01T10:30:00','2012-01-01T10:35:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-01T11:00:00','2012-01-01T11:40:00'),
                 (2,'Foxi','2012-01-01T12:50:00','2012-01-01T13:25:00'),
                 (2,'Foxi','2012-01-02T08:20:00','2012-01-02T08:25:00'),
                 (2,'Foxi','2012-01-02T09:20:00','2012-01-02T09:25:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-02T11:30:00','2012-01-02T11:45:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-02T12:50:00','2012-01-02T13:00:00'),
                 (1,'Fox ','2012-01-02T13:20:00','2012-01-02T14:00:00')) V(Usrkey,Username,DateTime_From,DateTime_To)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT Usrkey,
           Username,
           DateTime_From,
           DateTime_To,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime_From ASC) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Usrkey ORDER BY DateTime_From ASC) AS Grp
    FROM VTE)
SELECT Usrkey, Username,
       MIN(DateTime_From) AS DateTime_From,
       MAX(DateTime_To) AS DateTime_To
FROM Grps
GROUP BY Usrkey, Username, Grp
ORDER BY DateTime_From ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your time! Lamu, many, many thanks for your quick answer and solution. I've tried also with the ROW_NUMBER(), but your Grp column in the Grps CTE was my missing point. Thank you again.

Comment: @Hoira like I said in The answer, would be good to see what you tried before. Also, it's always nice to accept an answer as a solution if it works for you. :)